# nth-child selects everything

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to understand how the :nth-child works but don't understand why it is selecting everything below:

```css
    :nth-child(2) {
        color: blue;
    }
```

```html
<div>
    hello
    <h1>test</h1>
    <p>one</p>
    <p>two</p>
    <p>three</p>
    <p>four</p>
</div>

<div>
    <span>hey</span>
</div>

<p>hello</p>

test
```

Same happens when I do `nth-child(1)` but then `nth-child(3)` selects only "two" and "hello"

```css
    :nth-child(3) {
        color: blue;
    }
```

```html
<div>
    hello
    <h1>test</h1>
    <p>one</p>
    <p>two</p>
    <p>three</p>
    <p>four</p>
</div>

<div>
    <span>hey</span>
</div>

<p>hello</p>

test
```

Can somebody give me a walkthrough on how it's working so I can understand the concept?

Comment: :nth-child ... of what? div? p? You need to specify what element you want to select the nth of.

Comment: @RickardElimää Nope, `:nth-child` has no knowledge of the context it's used in and simply selects any element that is the nth child of its parent (including `<body>` or `<html>`, as seen in my answer).

Comment: You are selecting **every second child of every element**, starting with `<html>`. Fair chance everything gets `blue`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inspect an element to find out where it's getting its styles from. In Firefox, right-click an element and click Inspect to bring up the Developer Tools (there is a very similar procedure for Chrome):

[image: Firefox Developer Tools showing an element inheriting the color property from the body element]

We see here that `<h1>` is inheriting the color property from the `<body>`, which is selected because it's the 2nd child of `<html>`. Likewise, with `:nth-child(1)`, `<html>` is matched and everything will inherit color from that. It's smart to use `:nth-child()` only with a combinator targeting a specific parent/ancestor so you don't have unexpected inheritances like that.

Comment: i've understood it perfectly now. basically nth-child means that it has to be on the nth-position and must also match the identifier or tag name. when i didn't specify that it meant '*' and matched everytthing incluiding `body` and `html`. thank you.

Answer (score 3):

you forgot something. **nth-child** is a selector is selecting one specific item in your same list.look HTML, the h1 element is the second child of its parent **div** element, so it is selected and its color is set to blue. The other **p** elements are also the second child of their parent **div** element, so they are also selected and their color is set to blue.

so if you need color the **"hey"** , you need to upgrade the code to ,

```
div:nth-child(2) {color :blue;}
```

you need color the **"two"**, you need to upgrade the code to,

```
p:nth-child(2) {color :blue;}
```

you not done anything wrong. only you forgot select element in html.

I hope this help you.

Comment: This is not correct; the `<p>` elements are not the second child of anything and are not being selected. As I demonstrated in my answer, they are inheriting their color property from an ancestor that *is* getting selected.